# URL Chaning with Country

Tags: php, url

Hi guys I'm doing a website where you can choose a destination to send your flowers.

For example if the user choose Italy the URL comes: www.mywebsite.com/italy
If the user choose France the URL comes: www.mywebsite.com/france

Here's a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gbOQ.png) example

I have table with countries (maybe can help)

so i want to have the same page but with different url and even the flowers to show may be different.

Someone have an idea how to do this ??

Thanks if someone can help.

Comment: Use `.htaccess` for framing urls and in backend handle the request in single file.

Comment: Are you using a framework to develop this functionality? OR are you writing code with pure php?

Comment: i am using php html and little bit jquery

Comment: Ssikumar Can you be in detail pleas eim still learning and i never done this, or give me an example with code. sorry for being egoist but i want to see to learn :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with plain PHP, do the following:

Create a htaccess file in the root of your project. Make sure you have mod_rewrite module enable.

**/var/www/testPhp/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?(.*)$ index.php?country=$1&route=$2 [L]
```

When you call **http://localhost:1984/testPhp/spain** you will get in your index.php file a get param country, where you will have the country.

**/var/www/testPhp/index.php**

```
<?php

echo "Country: ". $_GET['country'];

echo "<br>";

echo "Route: ". $_GET['route'];
```

Comment: Can you explain me the route function ? for example . php ?

Comment: In $_GET['route'] you will have the rest of the URL. I mean, if you call: http://localhost:1984/testPhp/spain/flowers, you will have in the get route param 'flowers'. This will be useful to show different views depending on that param.

Comment: i cant do it the url is coming like this : 

http://localhost:8084/Frontend/test.php?country=Spain&submit=

Comment: You should name your test.php file as index.php and then include the htaccess in Frontend folder

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a PHP framework like Laravel you could create a parametrized route:

```
Route::get('/tours/{countryName}', ['as' => 'countryName', 'uses' => 'CountryController@index']);
```

Then in your controller, get the countryName and include the view based on that param.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i dont know if it is good or no because i didnt understand the code:P i never saw this.. there is a website or something where i can learn the laravel ?

Comment: Here you have the documentation about Laravel: https://laravel.com
I recommend you to use a framework like Laravel for making the website

Comment: so the thing i want (URL changing ) i can't make it with  normal php ?